# scipy.optimize curve fitting

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I was just trying to catch an ValuError thrown by the scipy.optimize.curve_fit function, but I realized it was not recognized as a valid exception.

Here is my code:

```
     from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

    ksi=( (185/((xdata_1/420)**2 + (420/xdata_1)**2 + 90 )) + (27/((xdata_1/800)**4 + (800/xdata_1)**4 + 5.50)) + (0.005/((xdata_1/2200)**2 + (2200/xdata_1)**2 - 1.95)) + (0.012/((xdata_1/180000)**2 + (180000/xdata_1)**2 -1.8))+ (0.01/((xdata_1/97000)**2 + (97000/xdata_1)**2 -1.95)) + (0.03/((xdata_1/250000)**2 + (250000/xdata_1)**2))  )

     def power(xdata_1,cc,dd,gg):
         global ksi
         return cc*(xdata_1**(dd))*(10**(-1.572*gg*(ksi)))
```

This is the full warning I get :

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (455,) (1772,)

How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: If the issue is with scipy curve_fit, can you post an example including that portion of the code?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. "I was just trying to catch an ValuError" but there is nothing about that in your code, "This is the full warning I get : ValueError..." Is that a warning or an error? which line of code is triggering it? "How do I solve this problem ?" What's actually the problem?

Comment: Given that ksi depends only on xdata_1, I don't see the need to muddy the waters with using a global on it. As for your warning, one of cc, dd, gg, or xdata_1 or ksi is a different length than the others, so your power function runs in to trouble in the broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, cause you didn't uploaded the whole code. Think that I had the same problem some while ago. I realized I had been using lists instead of Numpy arrays. Converting to arrays fixed it for me. The arrays needs to be the same size, too.